# Bresenham Algorithm using opengl GL_POINTS is pretty slow

Tags: opengl, framebuffer, bresenham

Is there to anyway speed this up?
I came to learn, accessing the Frame Buffer itself can do it quickly. but i dont know how... is there a way to do that in opengl?

Comment: The way to speed it up is to use OpenGL's own line drawing of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're implementing Bresenham for the sake of learning Bresenham then I suggest you put the "pixels" you're about to draw into an array (`std::vector` in C++). Then when you're done with the Bresenham "rasterization", pass that array as a vertex array to OpenGL and draw it with a single `glDrawArrays` call.

Otherwise, if your goal is to draw a line, just use a OpenGL line.

Answer (score 0):

To complement @datenwolf's answer, you're *probably* issuing a lot of drawcalls. That can and will make impose significant performance drawbacks. You don't even have to access the framebuffer directly, just make sure you don't make unnecessary operations between each point. There are multiple ways of achieving that, and indeed mapping a buffer is one of them. You can also stick to your own memory and simply "blit" the result to OGL.

And similarly, if you just want to draw a line, `GL_LINES` will pretty much always be faster and more convenient.